# Don't care symbol in Perl

Tags: perl, match, conditional-statements

I am wondering whether it is a Don't care symbol (X) in Perl.

I have a 50-bit binary input (actually, I used BigInt). If the input is matched with data in database, I would return a pre-defined value.

Let's say the data in the database is 11001100100010110111110110101001000010110101111101  .

If the input is X1001100100010110111110110101001000010110101111101, I would like to treat that it is a matched case because X can be 1 or 0. I know a way to split 50 bits in 50 1-bit and make an exception, but I would prefer to handle 50-bit together.

test.pl (main code, looks messy but the operation is simple, read database and input file and return an output file including a pre-defined value for the matched case. run by test.pl ) :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
#use warnings;
use Math::BigInt;
#use Math::Gauss ':all';
#use Math::Gauss;
use 5.010;
use List::Util qw(sum);

my $Astrip="cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.rml.";
my $Aj=0;
my @Aoutput;
my $At=0;
my $Agen;
my @Aitems; my @Aweights;
my @Aitems_p; my @Aweights_p;
my $Ap=0;
my $Aselected_p = 0;
my $Atotal_p; my $Arand_p; my $Alimit_p;
my $Ai=0; my $Am=0; my $Ak=0;
my $Atotal; my $Arand; my $Alimit;
my $Aselected =0; my $Attemp=0; my $Ane=0; my $Asum=0;
my $Al=0; my $Attest=0;

#### change edb workload - matmul
open(CSV,'database.db')||die("Cannot open edb file $!");
my @Aedb;

while(<CSV>){
    my @Arow=split(/\t/,$_);
    push(@Aedb,\@Arow);
}
close CSV || die $!;
#       if ($At == 0) { goto ASTART;        }
my @Ainput=do{
    open my $Afh,"<","test.input" or die("Cannot open an input file $!");
    <$Afh>;
};
for (my $An=0; $An < (scalar @Ainput); $An +=3) {
### First loop
$Attest = 0;
for ($Ai=0; $Ai < (scalar @Aedb); $Ai +=2) {
    $a = Math::BigInt->new("$Aedb[$Ai][1]");
    $b = Math::BigInt->new("$Ainput[$An]"); 
    if ( $a == $b ) {

    $a = Math::BigInt->new("$Aedb[$Ai+1][1]");
    $b = Math::BigInt->new("$Ainput[$An+1]");
    if ( $a == $b ) {       $Attemp=0;
        $Attest++; 
        $Agen=$Ainput[$An+2];
        if (not defined $Agen) { $Arand_p = rand();}
        else { $Arand_p =  $Agen;   }
        #$Attemp=0;
        for ($Aj=2; $Aj < scalar @{ $Aedb[$Ai+1] }; $Aj++) {
            if ( $Aedb[$Ai+1][$Aj]/$Aedb[$Ai+1][2] > $Arand_p ) {
                $At++;
                    $Aedb[$Ai][$Aj] =~ s/\n//g;
                $Aoutput[$At+$An/3]= $Astrip.$Aedb[$Ai][$Aj];
                $Attemp++;
            }
        }
    #$Aoutput[$An/3+$At-$Attemp]= $Attemp;
    }
    }
}

}
open(my $Afh2, '>', 'test.output');
print $Afh2 join("\n", @Aoutput);
close $Afh2;
```

database.db (database file):

```
0.1 11001100100010110111110110101001000010110101111101  rml_irf_old_e_cwp_e[1]  rml_irf_new_e_cwp_e[1]  rml_irf_swap_even_e rml_irf_old_e_cwp_e[0]  rml_irf_new_e_cwp_e[0]  rml_irf_swap_odd_e
0.1 11101100110010011011001101100111001001100000010011  3.923510310023e-06  3.19470818154393e-08    7.05437377900141e-10    7.05437377900141e-10    4.89200539851702e-17    5.01433479478681e-19
0.1 10000110001111010010111101110011001001011110000100  rml_irf_new_e_cwp_e[1]  rml_irf_new_e_cwp_e[0]
0.1 01110111010010000000101001000001100011011100011111  0.052908822741908   2.7185508579738e-05
0.1 01001100100100001011101000011111100101111011000111  rml_irf_new_e_cwp_e[1]
0.1 00111101000100001101010111010100000111100100100101  1.09213787524617e-25
0.1 00001000011110000101010110111000000111011110011001  rml_irf_new_e_cwp_e[1]  rml_irf_new_lo_cwp_e[1] rml_irf_new_lo_cwp_e[2]
0.1 01101001011110101011111011011011101100110100000101  2.28019753307221e-06    2.89026436307201e-14    2.89026436307201e-14
```

test.input :

```
11001100100010110111110110101001000010110101111101
11101100110010011011001101100111001001100000010011
```

test.output (a pre-defined value for the input and nothing for the unmatched case. I would like to have the same output with X10011...) :

```
cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.rml.rml_irf_old_e_cwp_e[1]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 1) You don't need `BigInt` for 50 bits; 2) You could just replace `X` with `.` and check a pattern match.

Comment: @Sinan Ünür, I'm pretty sure it won't work without BigInt if you want to use bitwise-AND numbers and your IV size is 32 bits. (Bitwise-AND is way more efficient than a regex match.)

Comment: @ikegami If that is the case, two 32-bit integers is still going to be faster than `BigInt`. I did not go into all the ways one can do this without using `BigInt`.

Comment: @SinanÜnür "." does not work for my case. Is there any don't care symbol except for ".". Also, I am sorry about my slow response. I couldn't not follow this thread since I moved into the other state and started a new job here.

Answer (score 6):

Using [Math::BigInt](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Math::BigInt): (Comes with Perl)

```
use Math::BigInt qw( );

my $pattern = 'X1001100100010110111110110101001000010110101111101';
my $mask = Math::BigInt->from_bin( $pattern =~ tr/X01/011/r );
my $targ = Math::BigInt->from_bin( $pattern =~ tr/X/0/r );

for my $num_bin (qw(
   11001100100010110111110110101001000010110101111101
   11101100110010011011001101100111001001100000010011
)) {
   my $num = Math::BigInt->from_bin($num);
   if (($num & $mask) == $targ) {
      say "$num_bin matches";
   } else {
      say "$num_bin doesn't match";
   }
}
```

Using [Math::UInt64](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Math::UInt64): (Faster than BigInt)

```
use Math::UInt64 qw( net_to_uint64 );

sub bin_to_uint64 { net_to_uint64 pack 'B*', substr( ( "0" x 64 ) . $_[0], -64 ) }

my $pattern = 'X1001100100010110111110110101001000010110101111101';
my $mask = bin_to_uint64( $pattern =~ tr/X01/011/r );
my $targ = bin_to_uint64( $pattern =~ tr/X/0/r );

for my $num_bin (qw(
   11001100100010110111110110101001000010110101111101
   11101100110010011011001101100111001001100000010011
)) {
   my $num = bin_to_uint64($num);
   if (($num & $mask) == $targ) {
      say "$num_bin matches";
   } else {
      say "$num_bin doesn't match";
   }
}
```

Using native integers: (Fastest yet if supported)

```
use Config qw( %Config );

sub bin_to_uint64 { unpack 'Q>', pack 'B*', substr( ( '0' x 64 ) . $_[0], -64 ) }

die("64-ints required\n") if $Config{ivsize} < 8;

my $pattern = 'X1001100100010110111110110101001000010110101111101';
my $mask = bin_to_uint64( $pattern =~ tr/X01/011/r );
my $targ = bin_to_uint64( $pattern =~ tr/X/0/r );

for my $num_bin (qw(
   11001100100010110111110110101001000010110101111101
   11101100110010011011001101100111001001100000010011
)) {
   my $num = bin_to_uint64($num);
   if (($num & $mask) == $targ) {
      say "$num_bin matches";
   } else {
      say "$num_bin doesn't match";
   }
}
```

Using packed ints: (Fastest yet. As written, assumes pattern and num_bin are the same length.)

```
sub bin_to_packed { pack 'B*', $_[0] }

my $pattern = 'X1001100100010110111110110101001000010110101111101';
my $mask = bin_to_packed( $pattern =~ tr/X01/011/r );
my $targ = bin_to_packed( $pattern =~ tr/X/0/r );

for my $num_bin (qw(
   11001100100010110111110110101001000010110101111101
   11101100110010011011001101100111001001100000010011
)) {
   my $num = bin_to_packed($num);
   if (($num & $mask) eq $targ) {
      say "$num_bin matches";
   } else {
      say "$num_bin doesn't match";
   }
}
```

Using strings: (Fastest because nothing needs to be done in the loop but the actual check. Assumes pattern and num_bin are the same length.)

```
my $pattern = 'X1001100100010110111110110101001000010110101111101';
my $mask = $pattern =~ tr/X01/\x00\xFF\xFF/r;
my $targ = $pattern =~ tr/X/\x00/r;

for my $num_bin (qw(
   11001100100010110111110110101001000010110101111101
   11101100110010011011001101100111001001100000010011
)) {
   if (($num_bin & $mask) eq $targ) {
      say "$num_bin matches";
   } else {
      say "$num_bin doesn't match";
   }
}
```

Same as above, but works without 5.14+

```
my $pattern = 'X1001100100010110111110110101001000010110101111101';
( my $mask = $pattern ) =~ tr/X01/\x00\xFF\xFF/;
( my $targ = $pattern ) =~ tr/X/\x00/;

for my $num_bin (qw(
   11001100100010110111110110101001000010110101111101
   11101100110010011011001101100111001001100000010011
)) {
   if (($num_bin & $mask) eq $targ) {
      say "$num_bin matches";
   } else {
      say "$num_bin doesn't match";
   }
}
```

Output:

```
11001100100010110111110110101001000010110101111101 matches
11101100110010011011001101100111001001100000010011 doesn't match
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $search_for = 'X1001100100010110111110110101001000010110101111101';
(my $pat = $search_for) =~ s/X/./g;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    next unless $line =~ /\S/;
    my $key = (split ' ', $line, 3)[1];
    if ($key =~ /^$pat\z/) {
        print $line;
    }
}

__DATA__
0.1 11001100100010110111110110101001000010110101111101  rml_irf_old_e_cwp_e[1]  rml_irf_new_e_cwp_e[1]  rml_irf_swap_even_e rml_irf_old_e_cwp_e[0]  rml_irf_new_e_cwp_e[0]  rml_irf_swap_odd_e
0.1 11101100110010011011001101100111001001100000010011  3.923510310023e-06  3.19470818154393e-08    7.05437377900141e-10    7.05437377900141e-10    4.89200539851702e-17    5.01433479478681e-19
0.1 10000110001111010010111101110011001001011110000100  rml_irf_new_e_cwp_e[1]  rml_irf_new_e_cwp_e[0]
0.1 01110111010010000000101001000001100011011100011111  0.052908822741908   2.7185508579738e-05
0.1 01001100100100001011101000011111100101111011000111  rml_irf_new_e_cwp_e[1]
0.1 00111101000100001101010111010100000111100100100101  1.09213787524617e-25
0.1 00001000011110000101010110111000000111011110011001  rml_irf_new_e_cwp_e[1]  rml_irf_new_lo_cwp_e[1] rml_irf_new_lo_cwp_e[2]
0.1 01101001011110101011111011011011101100110100000101  2.28019753307221e-06    2.89026436307201e-
```

In addition, you really ought to take a critical look at your variables. You have too many of them, and they are not named usefully. Also, if they all begin with `A`, the `A` conveys no information.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it right, you need the first (least significant) 49 bits to be the same.

For instance, set bit 50 for both then compare

```
if ( ($v1 | (1<<49)) == ($v2 | (1<<49)) ) { say "Match" }
```

where `$v1` and `$v2` are integers that may only differ in the 50-th bit for the test to return true.

The rest is about choosing how to form those integers from binary strings.

---

Using [Math::BigInt](http://perldoc.perl.org/Math/BigInt.html) as in the question (with [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami)'s comparison numbers)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Math::BigInt;

my $input_bin = '01001100100010110111110110101001000010110101111101';
my $input  = Math::BigInt->from_bin($input_bin);    
print "$input_bin  input\n";

# First number in @nums differs from input only in the left-most bit
my @nums = (
   '11001100100010110111110110101001000010110101111101',
   '11101100110010011011001101100111001001100000010011'
);

my $bits = 49;
foreach my $num_bin (@nums) 
{
   my $num = Math::BigInt->from_bin($num_bin);

   if ( ($input | (1<<$bits)) == ($num | (1<<$bits)) ) 
   { 
       print "$num_bin  matches\n"; 
   } 
   else { 
       print "$num_bin  does not match\n" 
   }
}
```

Prints

```
01001100100010110111110110101001000010110101111101  input
11001100100010110111110110101001000010110101111101  matches
11101100110010011011001101100111001001100000010011  does not match
```

There are other modules for this, firstly [Math::Int64](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Math-Int64-0.54/lib/Math/Int64.pm).

If you have no other use of `Math::BigInt` you can get your integers in other ways, provided your system has 64 bit support and Perl was compiled with it.

---

Using [pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html), where the string first need be padded to 64

```
my $input = unpack("Q>", pack("B*", substr("0" x 64 . $input_bin, -64)));
```

where `Q` is

> ```
> q  A signed quad (64-bit) value.
>     Q  An unsigned quad value.
>      (Quads are available only if your system supports 64-bit
>       integer values _and_ if Perl has been compiled to support
>       those.  Raises an exception otherwise.)
> ```

and `>` is the big-endian modifier, needed for agreement with `B` template in `pack`.

---

Using [oct](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/oct.html) is far simpler, if you don't mind turning off `'portable'` warnings

```
no warnings 'portable';

my $input = oct '0b' . $input_bin;

my $bits = 49;
foreach my $num_bin (@nums) 
{
   my $num = oct '0b' . $num_bin;

   if ( ($input | (1<<$bits)) == ($num | (1<<$bits)) ) { 
       print "$num_bin  matches\n"; 
   } else { 
       print "$num_bin  does not match\n" 
   }
}
```

The warning would be about this code not being portable between 32 and 64 bit Perls.  This should be considerably faster than `pack`.